# Centering \vdots in a sparse matrix with an even number of rows

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

I am trying to define only the non-zeros elements in a sparse matrix, thus using some `\vdots` where the entries are zeros and specifying the row when needed (using the `blockarray` command, with `\usepackage{blkarray}` in the preamble). My matrix only has 2 columns (or 4), so I can't center the `\vdots` like I would like (the problem would be solved if the matrix had an odd number of columns). Here's an exemple:

```
$\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
  \begin{block}{[cc]l}
   \vdots \\
   a & b & /K-1  \\
   c & d & /K \\
  \vdots \\
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}$
```

As you can see in this example, while I specified to center the entries inbetween `[` and `]`, the `\vdots` are centered on the first column. If I replace `cc` by any combination of `r`, `c`, and `l` it is still not satisfying. Also if I put the `\vdots` between any number of `&` on the right and/or on the left it still doesn't work.

The other solution I have (but not satisfactory either) is to add another column:

```
$\begin{blockarray}{cccc}
  \begin{block}{[ccc]l}
   &\vdots& \\
   a & & b & /K-1  \\
   c & & d & /K \\
  &\vdots& \\
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}$
```

But as you can see now the non-zeros entries are too far apart and the result is not really pretty.

Thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome! Please post a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), it will help other work on your problem!

Comment: Take a look at Mathmode.sty (a pure documentation file on CTAN, it shows how to solve many mathematical typesetting problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`blkarray` is able to do it without extra packages, just use `\BAmulticolumn`, which is the specific command for a `blockarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
  \begin{block}{[cc]l}
   \BAmulticolumn{2}{c}{\vdots} & \\
   a & b & /K-1  \\
   c & d & /K \\
   \BAmulticolumn{2}{c}{\vdots} & \\
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Two possibilities: the first one uses an additional column and the `@{...}` construct to decrease the inter-column spacing; the second one uses `\tikzmark` to place some marks and then places the `\vdots` using the marks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccc}
  \begin{block}{[c@{\hspace{3pt}}c@{\hspace{3pt}}c]l}
   &\vdots& \\
   a & & b & /K-1  \\
   c & & d & /K \\
  &\vdots& \\
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
  \begin{block}{[cc]l}
   \tikzmark{a} & \tikzmark{b} \\
   a & b & /K-1  \\
   c & d & /K \\
   \tikzmark{c} & \tikzmark{d} \\
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=0.5ex] at ( $ (a)!0.5!(b) $ ) {$\vdots$};
\node[yshift=1.7ex] at ( $ (c)!0.5!(d) $ ) {$\vdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. My terms are not exactly a b c d, but larger expressions. What is the default size of the additional column in pt?

Comment: @KKP The width of the contents plus `5.0pt` (the default value for `\arraycolsep`) on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

With `{bNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{c:c}[last-col]
\\
\Block{2-2}{} % prevent the vertical dotted rule in the \Block
a & b & / K -1 \\
c & d & / K \\
\\
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]